# Parse a string that contains a product ID, and option_id => variant_id pairs

Tags: php, arrays

I work with an ecommerce provider.

The product IDs are formatted as follows: XXXX_Y1_Z1_Y2_Z2

XXXX is the product ID (integer), Y is the id of the product option (integer) and Z is the id of the variant of the option (integer)

Y always has a Z

I need to transform this string to make it like this:

```php
[
     'product_id'  => XXXX
     'combination' => [
         Y1 => Z1,
         Y2 => Z2
      ]
]
```

If a product does not have declinations, its ID is : XXXX_0 and combination must be an empty array.

What I tried :

```php
$parts = explode('_', 'XXXX_Y1_Z1_Y2_Z2');
$product_id = array_shift($parts);

$combination = [];
if(count($parts) >= 2) {
  // TODO
}
```

What is the best approach you think?

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried to solve this yourself

Comment: Split on underscore, take the first (zero) index and set it to the product ID key. Then iterate two at a time over the remainder of the array, taking the first of the two-pair for the key, the latter the value, add add that to the combination array, unless the first key is `0`, where combination is null or an empty array. Write that in code and you're done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a function that will allow you to split it with nth number of variations.

```
$str = 'XXXX_Y1_Z1_Y2_Z2';

print_r(productStrToArray($str));

function productStrToArray($str) {
  $parts = explode('_', $str);
  $productId = array_shift($parts);
  $combinations = [];
  for ($i = 0; $i < count($parts); $i+=2) {
    $combinations[$parts[$i]] = $parts[$i+1];
  }

  return [
    'product_id' => $productId,
    'combinations' => $combinations
  ];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Explode and shift as you have done, then chunk into pairs, extract each `0` and `1` column and combine:

```
$t = explode('_', $string);
$result['product_id']  = array_shift($t);
$result['combination'] = array_combine(array_column($t = array_chunk($t, 2), 0),
                                       array_column($t, 1));
```

To work with more `Yn_Zn` you may want to make sure that you have an even number instead:

```
if(count($t) % 2 === 0) {
  // TODO
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Combining `explode` and a simple loop, stepping by 2 instead of 1 should be all you need.

```
$in = 'XXXX_Y1_Z1_Y2_Z2';
#$in = 'XXXX_0';

$bits = explode('_', $in);

$result = ['product_id'=> $bits[0]];

if ( $bits[1] == '0') {
    $result['combinations'] = [];
} else {
    for( $i = 1; $i<count($bits); $i=$i+2){
        $result['combinations'][$bits[$i]] = $bits[$i+1];
     }
}

print_r($result);
```

RESULT

```
Array
(
    [product_id] => XXXX
    [combinations] => Array
        (
            [Y1] => Z1
            [Y2] => Z2
        )

)
```

Or using `$in = 'XXXX_0';`

```
Array
(
    [product_id] => XXXX
    [combinations] => Array
        (
        )

)
```